# My B1/B2 visa was revoked in 2017. How do I apply for a H2-B work visa now

Tags: usa, visa

My B1/B2 visiting visa was revoked in 2017. How do I apply for a H2-B visa now?

Comment: Why was it revoked?  Was it cancelled with or without prejudice?  Did you overstay in the US?  For how long?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you had a previous visa revoked does not change the process you need to follow to apply for a new visa. It may impact your chances of being approved for that visa, but the process is the same.  During the application you will need to declare the previous visa cancelation (don't lie - it's not like they don't already know about it!)

Specifically for a H2-B, the process is started by the employer, or more likely their immigration lawyers. You should work with them as they will be able to provide details for the process that needs to be followed.  You will need to attend a US consulate during this process, but there are a number of steps that will need to be done by mainly by the employer/lawyers before you get to that point.